# Use UIPanGestureRecognizer to drag view from one position to limited position

Tags: ios, swift, uipangesturerecognizer

In my application I have an `UIView`.I want functionality such that user can drag the view from its original position to particular limited position for this I have used **`UIPanGestureRecognizer Class` **  and  in `gestureRecognizer.state == .Changed` condition I am changing the coordinates of view .I am able to drag the view to limited position when moving slowly but The problem is if the user drags the view very rapidly upward or downward the screen, then the view can be pulled beyond the limits I put on the Y position

```
 if(upperLimit > (self.topbaseConstrant.constant * -1))

   {
       self.topbaseConstrant.constant += gestureRecognizer.translationInView(self.view!).y

     gestureRecognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view!)

   }
```

I have been trying to solve the issue since last three days .Please give me suggestion 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your if statement checks the whether the current position of the constraint is less than the limit, and if the movement is very big, it can be bigger than the upper limit.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `min` function to determine upper limits

```
let newPosition = topbaseConstrant.constant + panGestureRecognizer.translationInView(nil).y
topbaseConstrant.constant = min(upperLimit, newPosition)
```

If you drag quickly and blow past your constraint, the `min` function will always return that upper constraint as your new position.

Comment: Of course without seeing more context to your situation I'm only assuming you want the min function. It's possible you want to use max.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this solution not working it has same issue

Comment: How can it fly past the limit if you used the min or max functions appropriately? Your constraint will never go beyond the bounds that you designate.